# Methods for computing boundaries of 3D sets

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology, surfaces

When I compute the boundary of a 3D domain, I always do it in a sort of intuitive way, if I can visualize it. But how does one proceed in general to compute the boundary of an abstract set?

> Are there some useful tricks?

For example, if I have something like

$$B=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2<4, \ z\geq 0\}$$
I picture $B$ as a sphere centered at $(0,0,1),$ cut by the plane $z=0,$ and we consider only the portion of sphere lying above the plane. So the boundary $\partial B$ should be given by the disk of radius $\sqrt{3} $ at the base and the $z>0$ part of the boundary of the sphere
$$\partial B =\{x^2+y^2\leq 3, \ z=0\}\cup\{x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=4,  \ z>0\}$$

> Even if this is correct, how would you prove it formally?

Next, consider some more complicated thing, for example take
$$V=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3: 1\leq x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 2, \ z^2 \geq x^2+y^2 \}$$

Here we have the intersection of a cone with a sphere of radius $2$ which has an empty hole inside given by the sphere of radius $1.$

The boundary of the cone is $\partial C= \{x^2+y^2=z^2\},$ while the boundary of the other surface should be
$$\partial(\{1\leq x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 2\})= \{x^2+y^2+z^2=2\}\cup \{x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$$

Right?

Now,

> - How do I compute the boundary of $V$ ?
> - Given the boundary $\partial V,$ how do I compute the portion of $\partial V$ lying on the cone? Is it $\{ (x,y,z): z=x^2+y^2, 1 \leq  2(x^2+y^2)\leq 2 \}$ ?
> - Given the boundary $\partial V,$ how do I compute the portion of $\partial V$ lying on $\{1\leq x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 2\}$ ?

Here is another [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3727026/computing-a-flux-through-only-a-portion-of-a-surface) of mine.

Comment: In general, if $\Sigma$ is a compact surface then its boundary must be homeomorphic to the disjoint union of circles. This follows from the classification of 1 dimensional manifolds. If $\sigma$ is not compact, you can have components homeomorphic to a line as well.

Comment: Also, rereading your question more carefully, you call objects surfaces which most people wouldnt. Your set V is a 3 dimensional set, not a 2 dimensional set. Its boundary is a surface, but it itself is not.

Comment: @Daniel you are right, I edited

Comment: An unsatisfactory answer would be $\partial V \cap Cone$ and similarly for the third point. It's just the set in the boundary satisfying that inequality. In general, intersection theory provides a more general scheme to get information about these objects. So what exactly about these sets do you need? Do you really need explicit descriptions?

Comment: @Daniel So, for example, the boundary of $\partial V$ lying on the cone would be $\{ (x,y,z): z=x^2+y^2, 1 \leq  2(x^2+y^2)\leq 2 \}$ ?

Comment: @Daniel For motivation you can see my related question that I linked to. But I also want to become better in computing boundaries in general.

Comment: I notice that your question does not refer to any definition of boundary. Although you've asked how to *compute* the boundary, I wonder whether you are really asking how to **define** the boundary?

Comment: @LeeMosher No, I am asking how to find the boundary in concrete examples using one of the standard equivalent definitions of boundary (e.g. as the closure minus the interior)